# Php-fpm corrupts my socket permission on startup

Tags: php, apache, sockets, fastcgi

I've installed Apache with FastCgi module, and PHP-fpm on a Centos server.

I configure FastCgi with an external server using the socket option:

```
FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
```

When I start my services (httpd and php-fpm) I got an error 500 when I request my helloWorld-test-page. But if I add write access to every user on my `php5-fpm.sock` file my hello world page works fine ! So I thought it's the good configuration...

But as soon as my services restart I saw my socket's permissions automatically updated and then my test-page doesn't works anymore:

```
srw-rw----   1 root   root      0 Nov  9 23:30 php5-fpm.sock
```

What is the good configuration for a socket file, and do you know what I should configure to make it definitive?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the permissions via the php-fpm "pool" config:

```
# /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 0666
```

The owner and group should line-up with the owner of the httpd processes.

Comment: How about Apache's suexec mod? Should I create as fpm's conf file as I have users?

Comment: php-fpm is an entirely separate process from apache, so it really shouldn't matter as long as the user lines up. I am not familiar with Apache's suexec mod as I prefer NGINX.